# How do you change the 'Done' text in a CAB?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, contextual-action-bar

Android's documentation says a lot about [CAB's](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html), but nothing about how to change the text for "Done". Does anyone know how to?

<sub>Other Links:</sub>

- http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/selection.html
- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#CAB

Comment: Please look into this, it may help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14964939/remove-done-button-of-actionmode/17144854#17144854

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The layout for "Done" are provided in [layout](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/action_mode_close_item.xml) and [layout-large](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout-large/action_mode_close_item.xml) folders in the framework. This button can be styled using the attribute `android:attr/actionModeCloseButtonStyle` in the activity's theme. The style only covers the `android:background` of the button, as mentioned in [styles.xml](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/styles.xml#L1917). Also, the string used for "Done" is within Android's scope (`@string/action_mode_done`). Hence, the string for the CAB cannot be changed.

Comment: perhaps this should be a feature request for the next version of the SDK?

Answer (score 3):

if you use ABS, this can help you

```
<string name="abs__action_mode_done"></string>
```