# Remove 'Tick' from Contextual ActionBar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I wanna get rid of the 'tick mark in the contextual action bar. It might be a method used in mode.(some method) ; but im unable to figure out which one (if there is any). minsdk=14

[image]

Here is the snippet:

```
private ActionMode.Callback mActionModeCallback = new ActionMode.Callback() 
{

    // Called when the action mode is created; startActionMode() was called
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) 
    {
        // inflate a menu resource providing context menu items
        MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();

        //TextView tv= (TextView)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.contextual_title, null);

        //mode.setTitle("ActionMode title");
        //mode.setCustomView(tv);

        // assumes that you have "contexual.xml" menu resources
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.contextual, menu);

        return true;
    }
}
```

contextual.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item
    android:id="@+id/toast"
    android:title="Toast">
</item>

 <item
    android:id="@+id/toast"
    android:title="NotToast">
</item>
</menu>
```

Comment: think this could solve your problem:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14964939/remove-done-button-of-actionmode

Comment: my bad. was loooking for 'tick' all over stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. These two links show a way to solve the problem. 
Will edit this answer once I implement it.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11277115/2534694

http://www.codercowboy.com/2013/07/05/styling-the-contextual-action-bar-actionmode-divider-or-splitter-for-android/

[Remove "Done" button of ActionMode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14964939/remove-done-button-of-actionmode)